# Trying to unmute a embed video in Shopify homepage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shopify

I have been trying to unmute a embed video in my Shopify Store Homepage but when I remove the unmute tag from the script the video doesn't autoplay or play at all. Can anyone help me out that what problem does my script have

```
<video src="my_video_url" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline=""></video>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('play').play(); },1000);
var video = document.querySelector('video');
video.muted = false;
video.play()
</script>
```

Comment: According to recent changes to browsers videos autoplay rules, you can autoplay the video with sound.

Answer (score 2):

You can check more here regarding the Google policy regarding the autoplay video along with sound [Link](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but my video is in the mid section of homepage and I want that when user swipe down and comes to the video section  then my video gets autoplayed with sound

Comment: I think you need to check intersection observer into javascript and when the video into the viewport, you autoplay and pause the video using JS.